Want to build chatbot with Rag and Tools (Normal Python Funcs), Rag is working but not sure how to incorporate tools in this current code
I have one working RAG implementation with llama and chromadb, Now I wan to call few APIs from the same implementation, from the docs I get to know about this bind_tools() but its giving empty answer. I have provided the full working code, could someone please help me with the tools implementation on this current code? Please consider me as a beginner. Thanks in advance!!
Sample output:
.{'input': 'Question asked...', 'context': 'Provided context....', 'source': 'Info about source...', 'answer':''}
CHAT.PY
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
from langchain_chroma import Chroma
from models import Models
import streamlit as st

# Initialize the models
models = Models()
embeddings = models.embeddings_ollama
llm = models.model_ollama

# Initialize the vector store
vector_store = Chroma(
    collection_name="documents",
    embedding_function=embeddings,
    persist_directory="./db/chroma_langchain_db",  # Where to save data locally
)

# Define the chat prompt
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", "You are a helpful assistant (Co-Pilot). Answer the question based only the data provided."),
        ("human", "Use the user question {input} to answer the question. Use only the {context} to answer the question.")
    ]
)

# Define the retrieval chain
    retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(kwargs={"k": 10})
combine_docs_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(
    llm, prompt
)
retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, combine_docs_chain)


######## Terminal Verison ###### [Run !python3.12 chat.py]
# Main loop
def main():
    while True:
        query = input("User (or type 'q', 'quit', or 'exit' to end): ")
        if query.lower() in ['q', 'quit', 'exit']:
            break
    
        result = retrieval_chain.invoke({"input": query})
        print("Assistant: ", result, "\n\n")

# Run the main loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()

TOOLS.PY
from typing import List
from langchain_core.tools import tool
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama

@tool
def validate_user(user_id: int, addresses: List[str]) -> bool:
    """Validate user using historical addresses.

    Args:
        user_id (int): the user ID.
        addresses (List[str]): Previous addresses as a list of strings.
    """
    print("I am here")
    return "Yes I can"

MODELS.PY
import os
from langchain_ollama import OllamaEmbeddings, ChatOllama
from tools import validate_user

class Models:
    def __init__(self):
        # ollama pull mxbai-embed-large
        self.embeddings_ollama = OllamaEmbeddings(
            model="mxbai-embed-large"
        )

        # ollama pull llama3.2
        self.model_ollama = ChatOllama(
            model="llama3.2",
            temperature=0,
        ).bind_tools([validate_user])

